# laravel select notifications for user by data field

Tags: json, laravel, notifications

i have default laravel notifications data field and default notification table 
only try to select some notification for user based on his notification data value i jhave created this function in User Model

```
public function notifications_data($col)
{
$notifications = $this->notifications()->where('data' , function ($q) use ($col){
            $q->where('appointment_id','0'); // query data as table
        })->get();

return ($notifications);
```

}

i have saved value in notification table col data { "type":"Appointment", "appointment_id":"0", "date":null, "updated_by":"","status":"0" }

How do i get this to get all notifications with status = 0 or appointment_id = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
public function notifications_data($col)
{
  $notifications = $this->notifications()
    ->where('data','LIKE','%"appointment_id":"0"%')
    ->orWhere('data','LIKE','%"status":"0"%')
    ->get();

return ($notifications);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
public function notifications_data($col)
{
  $notifications = $this->notifications()
    ->where('data->appointment_id', 0)
    ->orWhere('data->status', 0)
    ->get();

  return ($notifications);
}
```

Comment: Wow, what kind of magic is this? Is it a Laravel specific or a php thing?

Answer (score 1):

Using Laravel's query builder:

```
public function notifications_data()
{
    $notifications = DB::table('notifications')  //Specify the table you want to query
        ->where('status',0)    //Where status = 0
        ->orWhere('appointment_id',0)   //or appointment_id = 0
        ->get();

    return $notifications;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function notifications_data($col)
    {
      $notifications = $this->notifications()
        ->whereJsonContains('data->appointment_id',0)
        ->orWhere('data','LIKE','%"status":"0"%')
        ->get();
    
    return ($notifications);
    }
```

you can use whereJsonContains for it, you can checkout Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#json-where-clauses